# How to move UIScrollView automatically to make UITextfield visible based on keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uiscrollview

[How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present) - I have tried all the methods proposed in here, but my scrollview is not moving up based on keyboard. I want to implement the movement like in iPad notes as the text come close to keyboard, the document moves up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how I do that. Don't forget to set delegate on UITextField

```
- (void) scrollViewAdaptToStartEditingTextField:(UITextField*)textField
{
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0, textField.frame.origin.y - 1.5 * textField.frame.size.height);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:point animated:YES];
}

- (void) scrollVievEditingFinished:(UITextField*)textField
{
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:point animated:YES];
}

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self scrollViewAdaptToStartEditingTextField:textField];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self scrollVievEditingFinished:textField];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here is swift 3.0 version

```
func scrollViewAdapt(toStartEditing textField: UITextField) {
        let point = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(textField.frame.origin.y - 1.7 * textField.frame.size.height))
        scrollView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)
    }

    func scrollVievEditingFinished(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let point = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0))
        scrollView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)
    }
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        self.scrollViewAdapt(toStartEditing: textField)
        return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.scrollVievEditingFinished(textField)
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Provide more info of usage.